# Mininet: How to simulator benign traffic

Tags: networking, sdn, mininet

I am new to SDN network implementation.
Today, I want to use mininet to simulate benign TCP traffic, but I don't know where to start. Is there any open source script that can be executed or simply simulated?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely start with the [Mininet Walkthrough](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/).

You can also take a look at [the examples hosted in Github](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/tree/master/examples).

If you need an SDN controller (which will require additional study), you can take a look into [Ryu](https://ryu-sdn.org/), [ONOS](https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/ONOS) or [OpenDaylight](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/index.html#opendaylight-contributor-guides).

In terms of benign traffic, it all depends on what you define as "benign". Is [TCP traffic with iperf](https://openmaniak.com/iperf.php) benign? Probably. But benign traffic can only be identified when you also define "not benign" or "malicious". Are you talking about [ARP spoofing](https://linuxhint.com/arp_spoofing_using_man_in_the_middle_attack/) attacks? Are we talking about [Slowloris (slow HTTP)](https://www.kali.org/tools/slowhttptest/)? You need to define both types, and when you define both, then decide which "malicious" type of attacks you want to test. Then you could try to reproduce some [traffic from a .pcap file](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PcapFiles) captured by an organization that shows benign and malicious types of traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I will try it out!!